# What are the difference between generic Type(T) vs any in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics, types

### What is the difference between `generic Type(T)` vs `any` in typescript?

### Function 1

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
    return arg;
}
```

### Function 2

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

### Function 3

```
function identity<T>(arg: T[]): T[] {
    return arg;
}
```

---

> Function 1 & 3 is accepted if we passing any kind of `data type`, But the function 2 does not accept if we pass an `array`. **generic type is accepting all kind of data type on compile time**. but here why it does not accept?

***Also which function is good for better performance ( function 1 or function 3)?***

Comment: There is a good explanation for this on the official site https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics

Comment: @yurzui That is excellent document. this doubt coming from there only. Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no difference if this is identity function that just returns an argument and used without type restrictions:

```
const foo: any = fn(['whatever']);
```

And there is a difference for typed code:

```
const foo: string = fn('ok');
const bar: string = fn([{ not: 'ok' }]);
```

Also, the usage of generic type provides semantics. This signature suggests that the function is untyped and returns anything:

```
function fn(arg: any): any { ... }
```

This signature suggests that the function returns the same type as its argument:

```
function fn<T>(arg: T): T { ... }
```

Real functions are usually more meaningful than just `return arg` example. Generic type can benefit from type restrictions (while `any` obviously can't):

```
function fn<T>(arg: T[]): T[] {
  return arg.map((v, i) => arg[i - 1]);
}
```

But the benefits become more obvious when the function is used in conjunction with other generic classes and generic functions (and eliminated if non-generics are involved):

```
function fn<T>(arg: T[]): T[] {
  return Array.from(new Set<T>(arg));
}
```

This allows to consistently maintain `T` type between input (argument) and output (returned value):

```
const foo: string[] = fn(['ok']);
const bar: string[] = fn([{ not: 'ok' }]);
```

There cannot be any difference in performance because TypeScript types exist only on design time.

Answer (score 31):

There is absolutely no performance difference while using any of those methods, because all of these fancy things are just `Typescript` sugars and is only for development.

All the type checking is only in compile time ( when Typescript is transpiling/transforming your code back to normal javascript, in your server ).

Either way, when your code is shipped to the user's browser, this is how it looks :

```
function identity(arg){
    return arg;
}
```

But to explain the differences :

When using `any` you'll lose all type checking and safety checking that Typescript is offering, whereas, `T` behaves like a variable that will hold the Type that you don't know what it is going to be.

So

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

In above, we know that if `identify` accepts `number` , it will return `number` and so on, where as :

---

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
    return arg;
}
```

But now, you don't know if `arg` and the `returned` value are the same type or not.

---

The other issue that `T` will solve is when you're creating a method inside a class and it's expecting an argument which you want to make sure that this method will only accept arguments with the same type of the class's constructor's argument when instantiated.

```
export class MyClass<T>{

   myMethod(anotherArg:T){}

}
```

So using above :

```
let str = "string";
let instance = new MyClass(str);
instance.myMethod("other string") // will compile
```

Where as :

```
let num = 32423423;
let instance = new MyClass(num);
instance.myMethod("other string") // won't compile
```

Comment: Thanks, the only explanation that I could understand. :)

Answer (score 3):

The main usage of `T` is to avoid breaking the type when you call a method.

Example:

If you do :

```
let foo = new Foo();
identity(foo).bar();
```

The second line will be okay for the compiler, but not because he knows that `bar` exists in `Foo` type, because it's `any`, and `any` can have any method.

If you do :

```
let foo = new Foo();
identity<Foo>(foo).bar();
identity<Foo>(foo).notExistingMethod();
```

The second line will compile fine, not the third one because `Foo` doesn't have a `notExistingMethod` method.

any is often used when you need to create something in a more Javascript-way, meaning that you don't really know what is in your object, since Javascript doesn't have any types (I'm not talking about `es6` ofc).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is `any` on runtime and on top of that it's `any` at compile time in `JavaScript`. That's why there is `TypeScript` to provide type-safety at compile time.

The difference between `any` and `T` / `T extends` etc. is that you have type safety during compile time for example

```
protected typeSafety = <T extends String>(args:T):T =>{
    return args;
}

this.typeSafety(1); // compile error
this.typeSafety("string"); // good to go
```

If the function accepts anything you would have the error at runtime which would be too late.

Comment: good. But  why we need to use extend of T? Because T is accept all kind of datatype in `C#` . That's why it confusing

Comment: @RameshRajendran You have define what `T` has to be. Usually you would use that in a generic class which is extended by the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight example:

```
function generic<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

function nonGeneric(arg: any): any {
    return arg;
}

const name: string = 'karl';
const array: [] = [];

// Generic.

const genericName = generic(name);
const genericArray = generic(array);

console.info(parseInt(genericName));
console.info(parseInt(genericArray)); // Complains in TypeScript! (Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345))

// Non generic.

const nonGenericName = nonGeneric(name);
const nonGenericArray = nonGeneric(array);

console.info(parseInt(nonGenericName));
console.info(parseInt(nonGenericArray)); // Does not complain in TypeScript!
```

As we know, `parseInt` will not act properly when an array is passed to it. In the non-generic example you will only notice this when running the code. In the generic example TypeScript will alert you before hand (which is the entire point of type safety!).

### Why does one complain and the other doesn't?

The reason is generics keep track of the type. This only applies if the parameter type and the return type are the same. Otherwise there is no point.

### When should I use generics?

If the following points are satisfied:

- If your function accepts multiple types.
- The the input value type is also returned.

A further example:

```
interface Obj<A, B> {
    type: A;
    value: B;
}

function generic<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

const objOne: Obj<string, Function> = {
    type: 'foo',
    value: (a) => a
};

const objTwo: Obj<number, boolean> = {
    type: 6,
    value: true
};

const objThree = {
    type: 'hello',
    value: 5
};

const genericObjOne = generic(objOne); // Hover over displays: "const genericObjOne: Obj<string, Function>"

const genericObjTwo = generic(objTwo); // Hover over displays: "const genericObjTwo: Obj<number, boolean>"

const genericObjThree = generic(objThree); // Hover over displays: "const genericObjThree: { type: string; value: number; }"
```