# What is <T> used for as a type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've seen the use of  as a type in code. I've always figured it was a custom interface, but I've recently seen some code where it's been used, but I don't see an interface with the title T.

Here is the code:

```
  get<T>(url: string, navController: NavController) {
    return this.http.get<T>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + url, {headers: this.buildHeaders()}).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => this.handleError(err, navController))
    );
  }
```

Is this a default type and what does it represent??

Comment: `T` represents any `generic` type that is accepted

Answer (score 1):

It is a Generic Type Parameter.

A generic type parameter allows you to specify an arbitrary type T to a method at compile-time, without specifying a concrete type in the method or class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

T is a generic type i.e it behaves like a variable that will hold the Type that you don't know what it is going to be.

So

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

In above, we know that if identify accepts number , it will return number and so on.

Comment: If it's just a generic, wouldn't the default type be 'any'? So you don't really need to have identity<T>()  you could just do identity()?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023061/what-are-the-difference-between-generic-typet-vs-any-in-typescript to know the diff between any and T.

Comment: The whole point of generic in typescript is for strongly typed. So if you don't need strongly typed then just use `Identity(...)`