# Angular Best Practice on creating Generic method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am designing Api endpoints in Angular using HttpClient. This is a single service class which will handle all the Rest calls, it will be called from other service classes(which are currently making Rest calls).

What is the best practice to make a generic Rest method.

```
getApi(url: string, options?: object): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(url, options).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return throwError(error);
    })
  )
}
```

Or

```
getApi<T>(url: string, options?: object): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, options).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return throwError(error);
    })
  )
}
```

Will any of the above be able to handle : HttpEvent, HttpResponse or other such response?

Should I make multiple methods to handle?

Comment: you need to know the difference between any and <T> type. look the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023061/what-are-the-difference-between-generic-typet-vs-any-in-typescript. Personally, I prefer use <T> and avoid how much I can any. But, in some cases, this is impossible

Comment: Only use `any` when you cannot use `T`.

Comment: why you just not use directly HttpClient in your case ?

Comment: @bubbles right now each service is calling api using HttpClient but i wanted a wrapper on top of it so that all Rest calls can be done from one generic service class.

Comment: @Ben we can pass <any> if we are using <T> to define the type right?
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

const v: any = identity<any>(988);

So i think defining with generic <T> will be a better option!

please let me know your thoughts I am very new to angular and typescript

Comment: @Abhishek yes you can. `T` is a generic type parameter. So you can say `T` is type of `any`.

Comment: You are creating a useless wrapper which is even harder to use than the `HttpClient`, whose methods already use generic. Where is the benefit?

Comment: @HTN making a wrapper will help in generic error handling, header maintenance. So my team will be more into functional work than handling API calls. 
I think both the things can be taken care at Interceptor level but there are many other up side of this approach.
I think one major downside is creating a bottle neck as all my request is going to be handled by this service.. but i dont know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

**Please note, the answer is very opinion-based.**

Before I will show my solution, I want to share the idea beneath it. 
So, when I am working with TS I expect to have as **strict types as possible**. So, using `any`, `object`, or something like this is distracting in this context. I also want to avoid any extra typecast because it will lead to an error somewhere.

Luckily, TS is quite smart to help me with this goal, because it can identify types depending on the usage.

Based on this we can build something like this:

A very generic class that can everything we need (it can be extended with passing params to fetch, logging, counter whatever you need)

```js
class HttpService {
    get<TData, TResult>(url: string, data?: TData): Promise<TResult> {
        return fetch(url, data)
            .then(x => x.json())
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

But this class should not be used directly. I would advise creating a more strict and specialized service that will isolated fetch logic and provide strict types instead of generics.

```js
type User = {
    name: string;
}

class MyDataService {

    constructor(private readonly _transportService: HttpService) { }
    fetchUserInfo(userId: number): Promise<User> {
        return this._transportService.get('/some/url', userId);
    }
}
```

Now, I can use MyDataService without any typecasting and type guessing. One more benefit is that this service is very easily testable because you can substitute the transport module however you want.

Hopefully, my answer helped you.

Comment: will it be an  efficient way if some function is expecting Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>
as a response?

Should I handle the above case as Observable<HttpResponse<T>>   
?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid mixing the observable and promise approach. If you want to work with observable - transport (httpService) should return Observable<TResult> and concrete service should return Observable<User>.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter what exact object returning by transport service. Main idea to separate generic transport service out of the concrete realization